# How do I determine which UI element has focus in GTK#?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

In C# it's pretty easy to find which element has the focus; you just do this:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Whatever
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IInputElement GetFocusedElement()
        {
            return FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do the rough equivalent in Mono/GTK#. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the GTK Window (Mainwindow/this) is a **Focus** prop that returns a *Widget*. You can get and set it, it should ripple through all 'focused' container children till it gets to the last focused node.

So updating your code sample:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Widget GetFocusedElement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (((Widget)this.Focus).Name);
        return this.Focus;
    }
}
```